# SQL: Filtering data which has some records outside time interval and nothing inside

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need return only dates which has some values outside time interval and nothing inside time interval.

```
create table dbo.TestingTable
(
     [Group] varchar(20)
    ,[Date] int
    ,[Time] time
)

insert into dbo.TestingTable values
('ddo',20171108, '02:00:00.0000000')
,('ddo',20171108, '03:00:00.0000000')
,('ddo',20171108, '05:00:00.0000000')
,('ddo',20171108, '08:00:00.0000000')
,('ddo',20171108, '17:00:00.0000000')
,('ddo',20171108, '19:00:00.0000000')
,('ddo',20171108, '23:00:00.0000000')
,('ddo',20171109, '04:00:00.0000000')
,('ddo',20171109, '06:00:00.0000000')
,('ddo',20171109, '08:00:00.0000000')
,('ddo',20171109, '15:00:00.0000000')
,('ddo',20171109, '21:00:00.0000000')
,('kpo',20171108, '02:00:00.0000000')
,('kpo',20171108, '03:00:00.0000000')
,('kpo',20171108, '05:00:00.0000000')
,('kpo',20171108, '08:00:00.0000000')
,('kpo',20171108, '15:00:00.0000000')
,('kpo',20171108, '19:00:00.0000000')
```

So desired output for predefined @group, @mintime and @maxtime

```
declare @group as varchar(20) = 'ddo'
declare @mintime as varchar(20) = '09:00:00.0000000'
declare @maxtime as varchar(20) = '16:00:00.0000000'
```

should be [Date] column with dates passes condition.

In above case should return just 20171108 [Date], because 20171109 has some value inside interval between @mintime and @maxtime.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `group by` with a `having` clause that counts the times in the time period:

```
select tt.[date]
from TestingTable tt
group by tt.[date]
having sum(case when [time] >= @mintime and [time] <= @maxtime then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon, this works fine. I haven't expected is could be so simple :-)